# Why does FireFox window.onbeforeunload() only fire when a confirmation dialog is displayed?

Tags: javascript, firefox, onbeforeunload

If I register a Listener for 'onbeforeunload' console output will only be logged if a confirmation dialog box is displayed.

//Works

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { 
    console.log('onbeforeunload');
    return 'a string';
}
```

However, remove "return 'a string';" and the console statement will not be displayed.

//Fails

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { 
    console.log('onbeforeunload');
}
```

How can I record the event occurred without displaying a confirmation dialog to the user? This works in Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure that Firefox isn't simply just clearing the console upon loading of the next page?  [Chrome has an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2hfB.png) to keep it.  Unsure of Firefox, I don't use it much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is **always** being logged, it's just that without a confirmation dialog, the browser is navigating to the new page (or reloading) and clearing the log.

You can use the **Enable persistent logs** setting to preserve the message: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings